# Mp3 not playing in chrome but in safari

Tags: javascript, html, browser, amazon-s3, mp3

I have an mp3 File hosted on amazon s3. It plays when i open the URL in safari, but doesn't in chrome.

Here's an example: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/media.radio32.seerow.ch/songs/2017-08-03/04%3A10%3A24/2228490.mp3

Comment: not all browsers support mp3 encoding, you can try formats which are supported by all browsers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Chrome supports mp3, but not the one i linked. This one here for example is working http://blog.wemakeawesomesh.it/audio-formats-for-gapless-web-playback/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The File I got was encoded with an old MPEG standard (Layer 2 instead of Layer3).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at : 
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/media.radio32.seerow.ch/songs/2017-08-03/04%3A10%3A24/2228490.mp3

You have `%3A` (for colon `:`) used twice in your URL.

**Solution** : Do not use **colons** in a filename. They are considered as *special characters* in some systems. See [**this link**](https://superuser.com/questions/693816/why-cant-you-use-special-characters-in-a-filename-like-or/693819#693819) for more info/context.

Try renaming the file but replace colon with underscore `_` (or use dash `-`)...

Example: A file URL like below would work.
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/media.radio32.seerow.ch/songs/2017-08-03/04_10_24/2228490.mp3